# How to combine the three-layer architecture with the unit of work in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, design-patterns, entity-framework-core, unit-of-work

I use three layer and Unit of work Design pattern together but project have credential bug!

data Read from database but does not save in it.
Context Class Can't get changes and `CurrentTransaction` is null.

[image: Current Transaction]

How can I fix this bug?

In this project I have three layer and one protocol for models

1. Presentation project (dotnet core mvc with name Frontend)
2. Data project (for save and connect to database and have Repository classes)
3. Models project (it have my models. it's a global protocol for all layer)
4. Services project (for connect Presentation to Data and Businesses rules)

Data Code:

it layer have `Context` and `Repository` and `IRepository`

**Repository class**

```
public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class 
{
    private readonly FrontendContext context;
    private readonly DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;

    public Repository(){
        context = new FrontendContext();
        dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public void Create (TEntity entity){
        dbSet.Add(entity);
    }

    public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll(){
        return  dbSet.ToList();
    }
}
```

**IRepository interface**

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    public void Create (TEntity entity);
    public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll();
}
```

**Context class**

```
public class FrontendContext : DbContext
{
    public FrontendContext(): base(){}

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder builder){
        builder.UseSqlServer(@"server=(local);Database=CredentialBug;Trusted_Connection=True;TrustServerCertificate=True");
    }

    public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
}
```

Services Code:

it have `UnitOfWork` and `IUnitOfWork`

**UnitOfWork class**

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly FrontendContext context;
    public UnitOfWork(){
        context = new FrontendContext();
    }
    public IRepository<TEntity> RepositoryBase<TEntity>() where TEntity : class {
        return new Repository<TEntity>();
    }
    public void Commit() => context.SaveChanges();
}
```

**IUnitOfWork interface**

```
public interface IUnitOfWork
{
    IRepository<TEntity> RepositoryBase<TEntity>() where TEntity : class ;
    public void Commit();
}
```

Presentation Code

**Add service to program file**

```
builder.Services.AddTransient<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
```

Now I use it in my **Presentation** like this :

**Controller**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _UW;
    public HomeController(IUnitOfWork UW)
    {
        _UW = UW;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        IEnumerable<Person> people = _UW.RepositoryBase<Person>().GetAll();
        return View(people);
    }

    public IActionResult Create(){
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult Create(Person model){
        if (!ModelState.IsValid){
            return View(model);
        }
        _UW.RepositoryBase<Person>().Create(model);
        _UW.Commit();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
}
```

I test read data from database and correctly it work but add to database does not work correctly!!!

Comment: Your `DbContext` alraedy **is** the unit-of-work, and the `DbContext.DbSet<T>` properties **are** your generic-repositories - you don't need to re-implement those patterns all-over-again when you use EF.

Comment: Your `var tran` is a `bool`, which is not what you want.

Comment: You are writing to the entiry c# classes and not update the values to the database.  See REMARKS at following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.update?view=efcore-7.0

Comment: And always post code as text, not image.

Comment: I solved it. link of project sample is [github.com](https://github.com/Mohammad-Abbasi2559/Three-Layer-with-Unit-Of-Work) **Thanks to those who helped me**

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I will be soon edit question and add answer @Communtity

Comment: The question is unclear. The number of layers don't affect how EF Core/DbContext should be used. A DbContext already is a unit-of-work, it doesn't need any extra implementation. A DbSet already is a Repository. No extra implementation is needed. It sounds like you tried to create a low-level Data Access Object, what people mistakenly call "repositories". Well UoW and DAO just don't work together

Comment: That `GetAll` for example is an application-destroying bug. Nobody wants to load a 1M-row table in memory and yet, that's what this method will do. This can easily lead to deadlocks in busy web applications as multiple requests end up blocking each other. You find that in DAO implementations that iterate over rows like a cursor,  but not in any ORMs like EF Core that can actually retrieve just the objects you need.

Comment: The image of `CommitAsync` is another critical bug. `SaveChangesAsync` will save *all* pending changes in an internal transaction. It doesn't need an external one. EF Core doesn't even keep connections open unless it needs to load data or save them. An external transaction forces it to keep a connection open for long, keeping all locks taken until the external transaction commits. That's the  opposite of Unit-of-Work

Comment: A *high-level, domain Repository* over EF Core does make sense, by hiding from business code how the objects and their relations are loaded and persisted. The business code can assume that objects appear in nicely related graphs and get saved by magic, without having to bother with `Delete` or `Update` methods. This way, when you decide to switch from a relational database to MongoDB or Cassandra you'll be able to replace the ORM with something else. Switching from MySQL to Oracle to PostreSQL is the ORM's job, not the Repository's

Comment: @"Panagiotis Kanavos" it is just a sample code of main project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found answer and share it.

its bug created when our sampling `Context` class for each method. In this moment `transaction` stay in the previous sample `Context` and in `Context` of new method `transaction` is null, In result `commit` method **does not work**.

we need some changes in this design pattern

1. Add `Context` class to `Constructor` like this

   ```
   public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class 
   {
       private readonly DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;

       //get Context class from UnitOfWork Class
       public Repository(FrontendContext context){
           dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
       }

       public void Create (TEntity entity){
           dbSet.Add(entity);
       }

       public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll(){
           return  dbSet.ToList();
       }
   }
   ```
2. once for all methods sample `Context` class and send it to `Repository` Class

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly FrontendContext context;
    public UnitOfWork(){
        context = new FrontendContext();
    }
    public IRepository<TEntity> RepositoryBase<TEntity>() where TEntity : class {
        return new Repository<TEntity>(context); //Send Context class to Repository
    }
    public void Commit() => context.SaveChanges();
}
```